# Creating a service in Ubuntu 16.04 for a java jsvc application

Tags: 16.04, permissions, java, systemd

How do I create a service for my java application where I have to run it with apache commons daemon jsvc. The service should be started at system boot. I have searched and searched, read and read and tried alot of stuff, and nothing seems to work.

I have created a .sh script in the `/etc/init.d/`path and run all the necessary commands that the "web" suggested like `chmod 755 mydaemon.sh` and or `chmod +x mydaemon.sh`, does not work when typed without the `.sh`, so I do not know why people suggest that.
But it looks like this may be an old approach pre v.15 or so. Well at least I have found that some people say that it is deprecated and that systemd is the new black.

I have also tried to create a mydamon.service file in `/etc/systemd/system` pointing the ExecStart and Stop to my .sh script.
I have done all the `systemctl daemon-realod` -> `systemctl start myservice`. Here is an example of my `.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=Scheduler Test

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myscheduler.sh start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/myscheduler.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here is an example of my `.sh` script

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
#
# Provides: myscheduler
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start the myscheduler service
# Description: This file is used to start the daemon and should be placed in /etc/init.d
### END INIT INFO

NAME="myscheduler"
DESC="MyScheduler service"
EXEC=/usr/bin/jsvc
FILE_PATH="/usr/local/$NAME"
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
CLASS_PATH="$FILE_PATH/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar":"$FILE_PATH/myscheduler.jar"
CLASS="com.example.ApiApplication"
USER="root"
PID=$FILE_PATH/example.pid
LOG_OUT=$FILE_PATH/example.out
LOG_ERR=$FILE_PATH/example.err

jsvc_exec()
{
        cd $FILE_PATH
        $EXEC -home $JAVA_HOME -cp $CLASS_PATH -user $USER -outfile $LOG_OUT -errfile $LOG_ERR -pidfile $PID $1 $CLASS
}

case "$1" in
        start)
                echo "Starting the $DESC..."
                jsvc_exec
                echo "The $DESC has started."
                  ;;
        stop)
                echo "Stopping the $DESC..."
                jsvc_exec "-stop"
                echo "The $DESC has stopped."
                  ;;
        restart)
                if [ -f "$PID" ]; then
                        echo "Restarting the $DESC..."
                        jsvc_exec "-stop"
                        jsvc_exec
                        echo "The $DESC has restarted."
                else
                        echo "Service $DESC not running, no action taken."
                        exit 1
                fi
                        ;;
        *)
                echo "usage: daemon {start|stop|restart}" >&2
                exit 3
                ;;
esac
```

But nothing happens when I try to start it, currently it starts and stops immediately. It looks like my application cannot read one of my properties file which I am pointing to in the `/etc/environment` file:

```
quartzconfig="/usr/local/myscheduler/quartz.properties"
```

The main class of my application can be seen below:

```
public class ApiApplication implements Daemon{

    private static Scheduler scheduler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String path = System.getenv("quartzconfig");
            System.out.println(path);
            Properties props = new Properties();

            Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
            FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                    .configure(parameters.properties().setFileName(path));

            Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();
            props = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(config);

            SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
            scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

            scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ConfigurationException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Could not load properties... something went wrong!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(DaemonContext daemonContext) throws DaemonInitException, Exception {
        System.out.println("initializing...");
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("starting...");
        main(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("stopping...");
        // if process is stopped gracefully shutdown the scheduler
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
```

And as I can see from the logging `path` is null.

But what is more strange is I can start my "jsvc" app if I forexample place my `myscheduler.sh` in ex. `/home/john/Downloads/test` and manually start it like `sh myscheduler.sh start` then it works fine, but cannot seem to make it work as a service and on system boot `update-rc.d ...`.

I am new to linux, or at least not that well experienced, I am thinking that it might be some file folder permission access, I would love to just give it all a `chmod -R 777` but I am well aware of the consequences and what it could do to my system, tried it once or twice before xD. Running Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox so I just create a new image if it breaks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/893186/edit) and try to ask only **one** question. You can ask post multiple questions if you want to. As it is now, it is hard to see which of your multiple questions you want to takle first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, had to set `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` and `Type=forking` option in my `.service` file then it worked fine.